# Binary Search for a tuple with a given element value in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, binary-search

I want to find all tuples in:

```
vector<tuple<int,int>> tuples; //already sorted
```

that evaluate the next proposition to "true":

```
(get<0>(tuple) == val)
```

I'm trying to use the equal_range function to get a range:

```
equal_range (tuples.begin(), tuples.end(), val);
```

How can I express "val" correctly for the value comparison to happen in the first element of the tuples?

Comment: There is an overload of `std::equal_range` that [takes a comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) (binary predicate), so you can pass it a lambda or functor that compares the `std::get<0>` of your tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a tuple and ignore its last element like this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int>> v = {{1,0}, {2,3}, {4,5}};

    const int val = 2;

    std::equal_range(v.cbegin(), v.cend(),
        std::make_tuple(std::cref(val), 0),
        [&val] (const auto& l, const auto& r) {
            return std::get<0>(l) < std::get<0>(r);
        });
}
```